# Python 3.4 transmiting table, columns and values as variables using MySQLdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am using Python 3.4

I have this piece of code:

```
import MySQLdb

table = "my_table"
columns = ("column1", "column2")
values = ("value1", "value2")

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                       user = "user",
                       passwd = "password",
                       db = "my_database")

cursor = conn.cursor()

# execute an insert
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table column1, column2 VALUES (value1, value2)")

cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Q: How can I pass the table name, columns and the values all as variables?

I would like to do something like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s" % (my_table, columns, values)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it as a 2 step process as the execute method will escape strings.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(table, ','.join(columns), ','.join('[%s]' * len(columns)))
# Generates: INSERT INTO my_table (column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something to start with. However I get this error when I runt it: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: I have updated the answer to use String.format instead, do you get the error createing the sql variable or on execute?

Comment: I get the error on execute. The sql variable is created just like in your comment.

Comment: Looking at the [mysqldb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) documentation it seems they use %s instead of ?. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I have tried using '%s', but then the join will not work :) It returns %,s,%,s

Comment: Had to wrap the %s in []. Seems I actually meant `','.join(['?'] * len(columns))` the first time

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, you deserve your karma. After trying a bit this is what works  ','.join('[%s]' * len(columns)) .  Thanks!